# How to plot a wind vector from a database (netCDF4)?

Tags: python, vector, matplotlib-basemap, netcdf4

I'm plotting a wind vector over an Atlantic map.

To represent the vector I have use this code, where u, v, lon and lat are variables that I get from a database (in netcdf4 format):

```
ugrid,newlons = shiftgrid(0.,u,lon, start = False)
vgrid,newlons = shiftgrid(0.,v,lon,start=False)
uproj,vproj,xx,yy = \
map.transform_vector(u,v,newlons,lat,31,31,returnxy=True,masked=True)
Q = map.quiver(xx,yy,uproj,vproj,scale=2000,color='b')
```

I have to do something in a wrong way because as you  can see the graphic shows windvector between -100 and 0. However, my database have data between -75 and 0.

[image: m6jtr.jpg]

Thanks, I.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're not actually using the results of `shiftgrid`. Your code should probably read:

```
ugrid, newlons = shiftgrid(0., u, lon, start=False)
vgrid, newlons = shiftgrid(0., v, lon, start=False)
uproj, vproj, xx, yy = map.transform_vector(ugrid, vgrid,
                                            newlons, lat, 31, 31,
                                            returnxy=True, masked=True)
Q = map.quiver(xx, yy, uproj, vproj, scale=2000, color='b')
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't solve the problem. Anyway, thank you so much :))

Answer (score 0):

netCDF is not a database its a data format (and libs to handle it)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32693733)